# How to display data from a JSON post being sent by a merchant account

Tags: php, json

I have searched and searched for an answer to this but nothing seems to match my situation.

My problem is how to display data being received FROM the merchant

A merchant account wants to send me transaction data in the form of a JSON post.
Their sample code for receiving the data is very simple:

```
$inputData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$firstName = $inputData->{'customer'}->{'first_name'};
$lastName = $inputData->{'customer'}->{'last_name'};
$customerName = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
echo "customer name: " . $customerName . "<br><br>";
```

Ok, fine, but I don't understand how I can actually see the echo'd data.
Do I just have that page open in a browser and it refreshes itself whenever that page gets a hit?
That doesn't make sense to me.
Right now I am having it write 2 records.
1 record if the page is triggered (which it seems to do sometimes) and another record to write the data from the JSON (which is always blank, not NULL).
I would like to be able to actually see data so I can do more testing to find out what is wrong but I don't understand how to actually SEE anything.

Thanks...

Comment: the merchant is posting this to your webserver? then you'll never see the echoes. the output from those will go BACK to the merchant doing the post. you'd have to save the data somewhere, and look at it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this PHP script is being called by the merchant at any time, then you can append the data to a file on your server, like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$inputData = json_decode($json);
$firstName = $inputData->{'customer'}->{'first_name'};
$lastName = $inputData->{'customer'}->{'last_name'};
file_put_contents( 'filename.txt', date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) . "\t"
    $json . "\t" . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname . "\n", 
    FILE_APPEND );
```

This stores the time the data is sent, the json code and name. One row per request as a log of the requests.

Make sure you have write access to *filename.txt* and you can just read the data from the file (http://www.myserver.com/filename.txt).

The next step is to send the json back to your script manually, and make sure the data is correctly handled.

If you want the data displayed in your browser you need a push service, something PHP does not handle by itself. You can search the net for it or create a page which updates itself every minute, reading data from the file.

An even better way is of cause to store the data in a database.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  As stated, I am currently writing the data to a db but getting blank info.  At this point I do not know if the blank info is my fault or the merchant sending bad or no data.

Comment: If you put the lines `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` and `file_put_contents( 'filename.txt', date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) . "\t"
    $json . "\n", FILE_APPEND );` into your PHP, everything sent from the merchant will be logged into one file. Now you know if the data sent is bad!